# How make choose streaming in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, stream, uibutton, avplayer

I have main button "Playing stream radio", and two buttons with 64 kbs and 128. I must make choose the for example 128kbs and push the button "playing stream radio" and my radio will be play at 128 kbs. Also the same with 64. How it's realize? Big thanks for help.

Comment: i posted an answer for you marquee question, you can undelete and see it.

Comment: Please please please write me repeat...

Comment: are you asking how to know which button you pressed?